# Cannot retrieve entry vector of TCPDRV.DOS (Microsoft LAN Manager)

Tags: assembly, network-programming, dos

I am looking for API documentation for tcpdrv.dos.  The two resources I've found conflict on how to retrieve the call vector for the driver and neither seem to work.

Both resources say that you should take the file handle returned from a DOS-Open command (int21/ax=3D00h) and feed it into the following:

```
mov bx, [file_handle]
mov cx, 19
mov dx, offset request_block   ; ds=_DATA
mov ax, 4402h
int 21h
```

In which the request_block is initialized as follows:

```
sock_ioctl_s        STRUCT
   func             byte    ?
   status           byte    ?
   signature        word    ?
   pad              word    ?
   vector           dword   ?
sock_ioctl_s        ENDS

.DATA
request_block       sock_ioctl_s  < 2, 0, 4F53h, 0, 0 >  ; source1
;request_block      sock_ioctl_s  < 0, 0, 4354h, 0, 0 >  ; source2
file_handle         dword   ?
```

CV shows that request block returns from the DOS-I/O Control command set completely to 0.

Ideas?  Microsoft's LAN Manager Programmer's Reference doesn't discuss the TCP/IP driver at all.

Comment: I suspect TCPDRV.DOS doesn't have a publicly defined interface and is only meant to be Microsoft's networking software internally. If you want to do TCP/IP programming I'd suggest using a TCP/IP stack like the Waterloo TCP/IP stack or mTCP.

Comment: I've suspected as much as well, but was hoping that there was something out there from a third party.  The Freesock package, a set of Pascal wrappers for various DOS network stacks, includes one for LanMan, so the information must be out there somewhere.  This is for a system already running LanMan, so using another stack isn't an option.

Comment: Both the stacks I mentioned can be used at the same time as Microsoft's networking client. Remember MS-DOS is a single tasking OS, so there's there can be only one application at a time using the network interface, so it's not as big of a problem as you might think. See https://www.legroom.net/howto/msdos